# No audio on Win10, untill I plug in some hearphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphone-jack

I have a problem with my PC (Win 10 Home).

Every time I start the PC, the audio does not work. Only when I plug something in the jack port it starts working (and continues to work even if I unplug the jack connector)

Thanks

Comment: Outside of these headsets, do you have speakers, because it doesn't sound like you do.

Comment: Well, the question says, “and [it] continues to work even if I unplug the jack connector”, so either the wired headphones are magically working wirelessly, or the system has some sort of audio output device in addition to the headset.

Comment: Hi, it is an ASUS laptop. It has the built-in speakers, that works only when I plug (and remove) my hearphones. @Ramhound

Comment: So typically that is a software feature of the audio software for the audio device.  Do you have it installed?

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, it is this one: https://www.bang-olufsen.com/en/solutions/computer-audio

Comment: So have you looked through the options for the software for an option that disables your speakers when a headset is plugged in.  Linking to the software isn’t helpful unless you provide screenshots I won’t be installing software for hardware I don’t have